# Is there any way to create call recording app in flutter using url_launcher, permission_handler, record packages

Tags: flutter

i created an application for call recording using url_launcher, permission_handler, record packages.
but i am unable to access the recorded file. It gives error while playing the recorded file.

attaching the source coude and the audio file.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Source Code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:record/record.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class ProfileCard extends StatelessWidget {
  String name;
  String number;
  ProfileCard({Key? key, required this.name, required this.number})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                spreadRadius: 0.8,
                blurRadius: 2,
                offset: const Offset(0, 2))
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
      // elevation: 20,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            // height: widgetSize(desktop: 30.h, tablet: 30.h, mobile: 20.h),
            width: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(2),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                ),
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
            child: const RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: 3,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                'Profile',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal, fontSize: 11),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                      child: Text("  Name",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                      child: Text("  Address",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    const Text('Rabale', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),

                    Center(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Auto-start recording and make the phone call

                          _startRecordingAndMakeCall(number);
                        },
                        child: const Text('call'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // InkWell(onTap: () async {
                    //
                    //
                    //
                    //
                    //   final call = Uri.parse('tel:+91 7522922577');
                    //   if (await canLaunchUrl(call)) {
                    //     launchUrl(call);
                    //   } else {
                    //     throw 'Could not launch $call';
                    //   }
                    // })
                  ],
                ),
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      _createFolder();
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.folder))
              ],
            ),
          )
          // kpiScoresCard(kpiScores: sam)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

_createFolder() async {
  final permission = Permission.storage;
  final status = await permission.status;
  debugPrint('>>>Status $status');

  /// here it is coming as PermissionStatus.granted
  if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    await permission.request();
    if (await permission.status.isGranted) {
      var directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download/flutter');

      await directory.create();

      ///perform other stuff to download file
    } else {
      await permission.request();
    }
    debugPrint('>>> ${await permission.status}');
  }

}

Future<void> _startRecordingAndMakeCall(String phoneNumber) async {
  // Start recording before making the phone call
  /// call recorder is a class added for recording call (auto record)
  // CallRecorder.startRecording();
  var recorder = AudioRecorder();

  await recorder.start(const RecordConfig(),
      path: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/flutter/recording.m4a');


  // Make the phone call
  await _makePhoneCall(phoneNumber);
}

// Function to make a phone call
Future<void> _makePhoneCall(String phoneNumber) async {
  ///launch the call to number passed
  //   FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(phoneNumber);
  final ph = Uri.parse('tel:+91$phoneNumber');
  if (await canLaunchUrl(ph)) {
    await launchUrl(ph);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch tel:$phoneNumber';
  }
}
```

i created an application for call recording using url_launcher, permission_handler, record packages.
but i am unable to access the recorded file. It gives error while playing the recorded file.

attaching the source coude and the audio file.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Please attach the error you got as well.